# Exit all threads when one thread fails

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a program where a user inputted amount of threads adds and deletes to a doubly linked list. However, if a thread is preempted while adding or deleting an element and the next thread encounters the corrupted linked list the whole program should exit.

Is there some way to exit the entire program when one of the threads calls exit?

This is the function that the threads execute and I have set up exit calls when the linked list becomes corrupted

```
void *exec_threads(void* arg){
int *counter = (int*)arg;
int index = mult/threads * (*counter);
SortedListElement_t* element = (SortedList_t*)malloc(sizeof(SortedList_t));
for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
    element->key = &keys[index + i];
    SortedList_insert(list, element);
}
for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
    element = SortedList_lookup(list, &keys[index + i]);
    if(element == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find element %c in the list\n", keys[index+i]);
        exit(2);
    }
    if(SortedList_delete(element)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Corrupted list\n");
        exit(2);
    }
}
free(arg);
return NULL;
```

}

And this is the result I'm getting

```
Corrupted list
Corrupted list
Could not find element M in the list
```

Comment: Why not just lock the list when mutating it?   You're changing a few pointers - not going to take long, is it?

Comment: If you really want to terminante your entire process, just call exit(), or your OS 'TerminateProcess' API call, in the usual way from any thread.  I don't see as it's needed here, though.

Comment: The linked list is supposed to become corrupted. The point is to find out how many user defined iterations and threads it takes for the linked list to become corrupted on average.

Comment: I have tried it and the other threads continue to run.

Comment: What exactly did you call?

Comment: @MartinJames Check the edit

Comment: Ah.. exit(2).  That should termiante the entire process, ie.the OS should stop all running threads and then delete all the process resources.  The lot should go away.

Comment: Weird.  IIRC, calling exit() should terminate the entire process:(   What OS are you running?

Comment: It's some version of Redhat. I'm not exactly sure since I'm sshed into a server since it has the proper testing environment.

Comment: Oh.. OK, maybe something weird with the VM on the server?

Comment: I am fairly certain it isn't the server since no one else has reported problems with it.

Comment: Calling `exit()` *does* terminate the entire process, including all threads. If you only want a single thread to terminate, you can use`pthread_exit()`.

Comment: How many threads do you have trying to corrupt this list, and how intensively are they trying to do it?  What I'm thinking is that a thread is finding the list corrupted but is spending a lot of time blocked on the stdout lock/s and the convoluted output stream from your remote VM.  When it releases the locks after outputting, it is getting immediatelypreempted by other threads that have also found the list corrupted, and so are waiting on the lock/s.  This could result in several threads successfully outputting data before any thread gets to call exit() and termiante the process.

Answer (score 1):

The `exit()` function *does* terminate all threads.

Threads can be running simultaneously and can be pre-empted at any time (eg, just before calling `exit()`), and this explains the output you see.  It is likely that many threads find the list corrupted around the same time, then serialise on the internal locks that synchronise access to `stdout`.

Comment: Yes, it's possible that a thread becoming ready because a lock has been released would be given a temporary priority boost by the host OS and so be preferred over the thread that released the lock.  Since OP's VM probably has a limit on cores available, the thread releasing the lock may well be preempted and so denied execution.